# Weighted lottery

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to create a weighted lottery where people can have multiple entries and the number of entries is based upon a series of questions. For each question they get right, they get an entry into the lottery.

In my head, I've got a table with the participants' names and their total number of points (entries), then I need some way to have a list of the names with their multiple entries. So if my initial table looked like this:

| Name | Points |
| --- | --- |
| John | 5 |
| Larry | 4 |
| Andre | 2 |
| Mika | 6 |

Then my output list would look like this:

| Name |
| --- |
| John |
| John |
| John |
| John |
| John |
| Larry |
| Larry |
| Larry |
| Larry |
| Andre |
| Andre |
| Mika |
| Mika |
| Mika |
| Mika |
| Mika |
| Mika |

Then I could just use the default row leaders from the output table as the entry for the person and use a random number generator to pick numbers.

That being said, I'm open to other ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula-

```
=QUERY(INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A4&"@",B1:B4),"@"))),"where Col1 is not null")
```

`REPT(A1:A4&"@",B1:B4)` will repeat each cell value of `A1:A4` as per number in `B1:B4`. Then Split and flatten with make them a vertical array (column). `Query()` will return all the values except nulls (if any).

To make it more dynamic you may try-

```
=QUERY(INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(A1:INDEX(A1:A,COUNTA(A1:A))&"@",B1:INDEX(B1:B,COUNTA(A1:A))),"@"))),"where Col1 is not null")
```

And with new `LAMBDA()` functions.

```
=FLATTEN(SPLIT(JOIN("",BYROW(A1:INDEX(B1:B,COUNTA(A1:A)),LAMBDA(x,REPT(INDEX(x,1,1)&"|",INDEX(x,1,2))))),"|"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Harun. I used the one with the Lambda functions, and after adjusting to pull my A & B columns from another reference sheet, it worked great!